# VBA: Alternative to Restrict Method with categories?

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010, outlook-2003

My company just moved from outlook 2003 to 2010. We had a button that purple flagged messages and another one that send purple flagged messages to a server database by using flag filter. [FlagStatus] = 2
Since outlook 2010 doesn't use flag color anymore, I changed the code to use category, I successfully create a new category "readyToSend" with purple color. The problem is that I can't filter all the emails with this new category.
Microsoft seems to be contradicting themselves and my code doesn't work. I'm looking for an alternative.

from [Items.Restrict Method (Outlook)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa210275%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

> This method cannot be used and will cause an error with the following
>   properties:
>   **Categories**

I get that but then if you scroll down to examples you get :

> "This Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) example uses the Restrict
>   method to get all Inbox items of Business category and moves them to
>   the Business folder. To run this example, create or make sure a
>   subfolder called 'Business' exists under Inbox. "

```
Sub MoveItems()  
    Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace  
    Dim myFolder As Outlook.Folder  
    Dim myItems As Outlook.Items  
    Dim myRestrictItems As Outlook.Items  
    Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem  

    Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")  
    Set myFolder = _  
        myNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)  
    Set myItems = myFolder.Items  
    Set myRestrictItems = myItems.Restrict("[Categories] = 'Business'")  
    For i =  myRestrictItems.Count To 1 Step -1  
        myRestrictItems(i).Move myFolder.Folders("Business")  
    Next  
End Sub
```

I can't get this code to work. 
solution 1: If i can get this to work, I can solve my problems.
solution 2: Find another way to mark messages to transfer/transfered than category

thank you for help, will post code if needed

Comment: The example you use is moving items in the inbox to a folder called "Business" when the category is set to "Business". The problem with `Restrict` is only if you have multiple categories as `Categories` field behaves like a Text field. That beinh said, what error are you getting with this code? Does the folder "Business" exists in the same mailbox?

Comment: I get error Execution error '-2147352567 (80020009) Invalid Condition and stops at restrict line. 
Thx max for the reply, but I'm already passing threw the emails after I am just using filter so I don't have to go threw all emails everytime someone wants to mark and send emails to the server.

Comment: sorry I did not see your replly as it was not below my answer. In wich line exactly is the error coming, "restrict line" is not quite clear. Maybe set a marker in the code... by the way for me the code works (Outlook 2013)

Answer (score 0):

if the filter does not work, I would do it other way round:

- select all items (istead of the already filtered)
- check each item if it has the category you are looking for

this would look about like this:

```
Set myItems = myFolder.Items  
''=> this we leave away''Set myRestrictItems = myItems.Restrict("[Categories] = 'Business'")  
For i =  myItems.Count To 1 Step -1  
    if instr(myItems(i).Categories, "readyToSend") <> 0 then myItems(i).Move myFolder.Folders("Business")  
Next
```

it might take a Little longer to run, but the diff should not be to bad.
I hope this helps,
Max

Comment: Performance-wise, this could be a problem for users with a lot (hundreds or thousands) of mails (for example, after a long-term absence).

Answer (score 0):

Bit late with an answer, but I have found a working solution at [MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brijs/archive/2008/11/28/condition-is-not-valid-error-on-items-find-for-appointment-item-using-globalappointmentid-as-filter.aspx)

It needed a bit digging in MFCMapi to get the right string.

For appointment item, the restrict string is:
"@SQL=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/Keywords"" = '" & sCategoryName & "'"

You need to check if the same string works for message or dig out the correct one.